# Why does my Raspberry Pi 4B keep returning to the loading screen when closing windows?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian, boot, raspberry-pi4

There's 8GB of RAM, and about 800GiB of free storage.

I think it might be due to the [touchscreen I'm using](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.3inch_DSI_LCD?Amazon) but I'm not sure why.

As part of the installation I added this to the config.txt file:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
```

[I include the logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N5azWyfDE8wvvDgxgxVBCMvi79c775lA/view?usp=drivesdk) I got from journalctl here. I hope these are the right ones, I'm a noob so I'm not sure.

Any idea what might cause this? How to prevent it from doing so? It's almost like a partial reboot; it hangs for a second, then cuts to a black screen with a blinking cursor like in a terminal, then shows the login prompt.

This is on Raspbian, latest version.